# Analyzing electron-positron scattering cross section in detail

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering-cross-section

It can be found in any quantum electrodynamics book that the cross section for electron-positron scattering in the high energy limit is 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d} \sigma}{\sin \theta \,  \mathrm{d} \theta} = \frac{k}{E^2}  \left( \dfrac{1+\cos^{4}\theta/2}{\sin^{4} \theta/2} + \dfrac{1+\cos^{2} \theta/2}{2} - 2 \dfrac{\cos^{4} \theta/2}{\sin^{2} \theta/2} \right) 
\end{equation}
where $k$ is a constant. The first term is due to the $t$-channel scattering, second from the $s$-channel annihilation, and the third is the interference of the two.  Below is a Mathematica plot of three terms plotted separately.

[image: Blue: 1st term ($t$-channel annihilation), Pink: 2nd term ($s$-channel scattering), Green: 3rd term (interference)]

Blue: 1st term ($s$-channel annihilation), Pink: 2nd term ($t$-channel scattering), Green: 3rd term (interference)

My questions are:

1. Why is the $s$-channel contribution so low?
2. If you see graph carefully, the $s$-channel curve is not monotonously increasing/decreasing as you can see below:

[image: T channel]

Please explain this shape.

3. What exactly does interference mean?

Comment: seeking_infinity, please think twice before "correcting" s-channel and t-channel in the question again. The original question had it all upside-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first make sure to look through the basics of [Bhabha scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering) and then let's start from the end:

### About interference

In quantum mechanics, amplitudes add linearly.
In this case, the $t$-channel scattering and $s$-channel amplitudes, that can be neatly described by the corresponding Feynman diagrams, are added to give the full amplitude for the $e^+e^-\to e^+e^-$ process.
In this case the amplitudes have opposite signs [(see basics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering), such that $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}_t-\mathcal{M}_s$.

Since observables are proportional to the modulo of the amplitude squared, you will have something like $|\mathcal{M}|^2=|\mathcal{M}_t-\mathcal{M}_s|^2=|\mathcal{M}_t|^2+|\mathcal{M}_s|^2-2|\mathcal{M}_t\mathcal{M}_s|$.

So that last piece is the result of the (quantum mechanical) interference of the amplitudes.

For a more visual explanation have a look at pages 35-38 of [this lecture](http://www.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/~coulon/Lectures/SM/Free_PDFs/Lecture_HC_4.pdf#page=35).

### About the size of the $s$-channel annihilation contribution

First of all, it is not small.
The issue is that since what we labelled the "$t$-channel scattering contribution" is divergent at low angles (more on that below,) it looks small*er*.
But note that only the sum of all three pieces is observable, so this sort of per-piece analysis is flawed to some extent.

### About the shape of the $s$-channel annihilation contribution

Regarding the shape, let me first discuss the $t$-channel scattering shape: it is monotonically changing, rapidly increasing to small scattering angles as you correctly observed.
That is intuitively understandable since the probability of not scattering at all should be huge: why scatter when you can just do nothing?
Of course, as hinted above, looking at a single amplitude-squared is bogus.

Now, in the case of $s$-channel annihilation, the situation is very different.
You are not scattering, but you actually have an intermediate product of the annihilation, typically a virtual photon (that can go through the Z boson pole).
It is then this virtual photon (a spin-1 "particle") that decays.
That decay has the [well-known $(1+\cos^2\theta)$ dependency](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.2219).
Now, I am not sure about your calculations, in particular the factors $1/2$ in all the  $\theta/2$ in the right-hand-side but that may be the reason you get what you get and not something more familiar.
Experimentalists usually plot $x=\cos\theta$, between $x=-1$ and $x=+1$ and you can see the result in page 37 of [this lecture](http://www.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/~coulon/Lectures/SM/Free_PDFs/Lecture_HC_4.pdf#page=35).

Comment: I know the relative minus sign in $\mathcal{M_{t}}$ and $\mathcal{M_{s}}$ comes because of exchange in two fermions. But I am not comfortable with the idea that we are subtracting the amplitude of two possible processes.

Comment: There is nothing being subtracted; there is only the amplitudes having opposite signs.
(Destructive) interference is a very basic property even of classical wave mechanics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)